# C++ unordered_map errors when pointing to a vector

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

I am having some issues using the unordered map below:

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> FriendHash;
```

When I compile my code I get the following errors:

```
usr/lib/c++/v1/type_traits:922:38: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >'

usr/lib/c++/v1/unordered_map:360:71: No member named 'value' in 'std::__1::is_empty<std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you use needs to be defined. You need to include string here possibly along with other dependencies.

```
#include <string>
```